# multiply data frame by x vectors in another df, return x new data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

```
df1 = data.frame("a" = c(.2, 0, .3), "b" = c(.3, .1, .4), "c" = c(.5,.9, .3))
df2 = data.frame("X"= c(41, 40, 100), "Y" = c(19, 20, 15), "Z" = c(8, 6, 10))
```

It's easy enough to multiply each row of `df1` by the corresponding row of the first column of `df2`:

```
dfX = df1 * df2[,1]
```

And then sum the columns:

```
dfX = colSums(dfX)
```

which returns

```
  a    b    c 
38.2 56.3 86.5
```

How can I perform this operation over every column in `df2`, generating data frames dfX, dfY, dfZ, etc.? I would like to then row bind these new data frames and then transpose, producing:

```
    X    Y    Z
a 38.2  8.3  4.6
b 56.3 13.7  7.0
c 86.5 32.0 12.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sapply` to multiply each column of `df2` with `df1` and then take `colSums` over them.

```
sapply(df2, function(x) colSums(df1 * x))

#    X    Y    Z
#a 38.2  8.3  4.6
#b 56.3 13.7  7.0
#c 86.5 32.0 12.4
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! `data.frame(lapply(df2, function (x) t(rbind(colSums(df1 * x))))` appears to take care of the rest

Comment: @hoho I just added a more simplified version.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with crossproduct

```
t(df1) %*% as.matrix(df2)
#     X    Y    Z
#a 38.2  8.3  4.6
#b 56.3 13.7  7.0
#c 86.5 32.0 12.4
```